# Need to add account names to exclude sending emails

Tags: apex, trigger, class, singleemailmessage

[image][image]I'm trying to exclude certain accounts in order to exclude them in sending survey emails. COuld see that I have included account id, which is very hard coding. I know. But there are some more accounts which I want to exclude but not this way. I want to exclude them with their names. Coz they have pretty close names. So I felt it's better to exclude them by names. I would really appreciate your help. New bee in coding.

```
> public  static void Sendnotification(List<case> CaseLst,Map<id,case>
> OldMap){
>         set<id> contactidset=new set<id>();
>         set<id> RecordOwnerIDSet=new Set<id>();


    for(Case cs:CaseLst){
        if(cs.Status == 'Closed' ){
           if(**cs.AccountId != '00130000007Z0nL'** && cs.Age_days__c <= 30 && cs.Survey_Type__c == 'Agent' && cs.Problem_Type__c != 'Sales/Trial Request' && cs.Parentid == null ) {                
              contactidset.add(cs.contactid);
           }                              
         } 

       RecordOwnerIDSet.add(cs.ownerid);  
    }

     Map<id,User> UsrMap=new Map<id,User>();
    if(RecordOwnerIDSet!=null && RecordOwnerIDSet.size()>0){
        for(user usr:[select id,name, profileid,profile.name from user where id in:RecordOwnerIDSet]){
            UsrMap.put(usr.id,usr);
        }
    }


    List<Licensee__c> LicsnList=new List<Licensee__c>();
    if(contactidset!=null && contactidset.size()>0){
        LicsnList =[select id,User__c,User__r.email,   Support_Status__c, SN__r.Banned__c, SN__r.Block_Support__c, SN__r.Bad_Debt__c from Licensee__c where User__c in:contactidset];
    }
   // Set<string> ContactEmailIDSet= new Set<string>();
   Map<string,string> ContactLicsnMap=new Map<string,string>();
    if(LicsnList!=null && LicsnList.size()>0){
        for(Licensee__c LIC:LicsnList){
            //if(LIC.AMSEnd__c>system.today())
              if(LIC.No_Support__c == false && (LIC.User__r.Nb_Days_since_last_survey__c > 30 || LIC.User__r.Nb_Days_since_last_survey__c == 0) ) {
                //ContactEmailIDSet.add(User__r.email);
                ContactLicsnMap.put(LIC.User__c,LIC.User__r.email);

            }

    }
      List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > maillist = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
     EmailTemplate et=[Select Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'Customer_Satisfaction_05_29_14_43'];
    for(Case cs:CaseLst){
    if(cs.Status == 'Closed' && OldMap.get(cs.id).Status!='Closed' && UsrMap.containskey(cs.ownerid) && UsrMap.get(cs.ownerid).profile.name!=null &&  (UsrMap.get(cs.ownerid).profile.name =='Customer Care Manager' || UsrMap.get(cs.ownerid).profile.name =='Customer Care' || UsrMap.get(cs.ownerid).profile.name =='Customer Care Knowledge') && ContactLicsnMap.containskey(cs.contactid) && ContactLicsnMap.get(cs.contactid)!=null){            


        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       mail.setTargetObjectId(cs.contactid);
        mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
       /*  String subject = et.Subject;
        String htmlBody = et.HtmlValue;
        htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Contact.FirstName}', cs.contactid);
        htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Case.Agent__c}', cs.agent__c);
        htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Case.CaseNumber}', cs.CaseNumber);*/
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('iBwave Support');
       // mail.setSubject(subject);
        //mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
        mail.setWhatId(cs.id);
        String[] toAddress = new String[] {ContactLicsnMap.get(cs.contactid)};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        maillist.add(mail);

     } 
   }
   if(maillist!=null && maillist.size()>0){
     Messaging.sendEmail(maillist);
   }

   }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a `Checkbox` field named something like `Exclude_From_Surveys__c`. Then you can just update your code to act based on the value:

```
if (!cs.Account.Exclude_From_Surveys__c && otherCriteria)
{
    // add to set, send email, etc.
}
```

In this way, you can make wether the email is sent to a particular `Account` or not a simple data loading exercise.

---

If you find the checkbox approach unpalatable, you could add a `List Custom Setting` to enumerate the `Account Names` you want to exclude. Then, you don't need to modify the `Account` data at all, but can still exclude them in a configurable way. You wouldn't even need to add any custom fields, simply use the `Name` on the `Custom Setting` to determine the `Name` to exclude.

```
Set<Id> excludedAccountIds = new Map<Id, Account>([
    SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name IN :AccountSurveyBlacklist__c.getAll().keySet()
]).keySet();

for (Case record : trigger.new)
{
    if (record.Status == 'Closed' && !excludedAccountIds.contains(record.AccountId) && ...)
    {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

Using this approach, if you wanted to blacklist all `Account` records whose `Name` is `Ericsson` or `Ericsson US`, you would create two `AccountSurveyBlacklist__c` records, one for each `Name`.

Comment: There are several accounts to exclude. It would be hard to have checkbox and checking them by going into each account record. There are some accounts which does have pretty close name. For example: Ericsson, Ericsson US. It would be easier to mention name of the account in the code (!cs.Account.Name.contains('Ericsson')

Comment: It might seem easier now, but then when you have to tweak the logic in a few months, not so much. It is very easy to set a checkbox on the records you want to exclude.

Comment: I really appreciate your idea. But this idea, removing certain accounts, is not permanent. It's very temporary. We would like to include them in the code.

Comment: Using code is much more permanent than creating a data dependency. When you want to include them again, simply uncheck the box...it's just a data loading exercise at that point.

Comment: Our team has decided to go include in the code!! Can't change the decision now.. I appreciate if you could help out in excluding them in the code.

Comment: @Gidy - Bad decision that will come back to bite you later. Good luck

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've created a custom setting as you said and included the code as you've written.. on testing I'm still receiving the email

Comment: @Gidy You have to include the exact names of any `Account` you wish to exclude. It will only blacklist verbatim. Try running the first part where you get the `excludedAccountIds` via `Execute Anonymous` and see what records you have actually blacklisted.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I tried running Execute Anonymous to check for Account Ids and don't see anything .. attached the picture

Comment: @Gidy That screenshot does not help *at all*. What exactly did you debug? Can you confirm that you have set up records in the `Custom Setting` whose `Name` values exactly match the `Name` values on `Account` records you wish to exclude?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Attached a new picture... you could see the account name that I'm trying to exclude from the list. And, the account name and account name in the custom setting are same

Comment: **Do not create any custom fields on the custom setting.** Set the standard `Name` field to `Crown Castle USA Inc.`. The way you have it set up currently, it would only block emails to `Account` records whose `Name = 'Name'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48196/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-gidy).